# How to run IE metro version without making it default browser?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use the IE10 App without making Internet Explorer the default browser?](https://superuser.com/questions/490415/is-it-possible-to-use-the-ie10-app-without-making-internet-explorer-the-default)

Refering to my earlier question : [Unable to install Internet Explorer app in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/501274/unable-to-install-internet-explorer-app-in-windows-8/)

While solving it, apparently I cannot use IE Metro version without making it my default browser. Is there a workaround?

Comment: NO, you would not be able to access IE 10 Modern UI App, if it is not the default browser.

Answer (score 0):

There is a promising looking Powershell script at [powertoe.wordpress.com](http://powertoe.wordpress.com/2012/11/02/get-a-list-of-metro-apps-and-launch-them-in-windows-8-using-powershell/).